# Replacing NA Values in a data frame using a nested for loop and if, else if, else

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, nested, na

I have been trying to replace the NAs of the "URL" column, in the loop: "url_col", with something like "".
So far I have this:

```
url_col <- which(colnames(data_mat) == "URL") 

for (c in 1:ncol(data_mat)) {
  for (r in 1:nrow(data_mat)) {
    if(c == lit_col) {            
      cell <-  flatten(data_mat[r,c]) 
    } else if (c == url_col & is.na(data_mat[[r]])){       
      cell <- gsub("NA", "", cell)                         
    } else {
      cell <- unlist(data_mat[r,c])
      cell <- paste(cell, collapse = ", ")
    }
   }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
#is.na(data_mat[[r,c]])) 
#is.na([r])
```

But I get the warning "the condition has length > 1" or the results are not what I expected

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(df, 10))` of your data?

Comment: even just 5 records is a lot of information. My URL column is the last one and it contains this:

, URL = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c("Athenatempel Phase IVb", 
"Bad des Ilyas Bey Komplexes", "Hafentor am Humeitepe", "Tabernae am Athenatempel", 
"Heilige Straße"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: alternatively, you can create a fake data frame without the sensitive information. I imagine this is an easy task to solve, but without sufficient reproducible example and explanation of desired output, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Now I have something small that represents the matter:

Comment: mi_df <- data.frame(
  "identifier" = 1:5, 
  "description" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
  "period" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 10),
  "literature" = as.character(c("book1", "book2", NA, NA, "book3")),
  "URL" = c(NA, "web1", NA, "web2",NA)
)

Comment: lit_col_t <- which(colnames(mi_df) == "literature") 
url_col_t <- which(colnames(mi_df) == "URL")

for (c in 1:ncol(mi_df)) {
  for (r in 1:nrow(mi_df)) {
    if(c == lit_col_t) {            
      cell <-  flatten(mi_df[r,c]) 
    } else if (c == url_col_t & is.na(mi_df[[r]])){         
      cell <- gsub("NA", "", cell)                         
    } else {
      cell <- unlist(mi_df[r,c])
      cell <- gsub("NA; ", "", cell) # gsub() used for replacement operations
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you add your data in your question and add relevant libraries e.g. the library for the function `flatten`? :)

Comment: The data is extensive.
In the "lit_col" column the information looks like this:
[[47]][[2]]
[[47]][[2]]$quotation
[1] "W. Müller-Wiener, Mittelalterliche Befestigungen im südlichen Ionien, IstMitt 11, 1961,"

Here I'm using flatten() to create a non-nested list from a list.

My problem is only with the NA of the "url_col" column, inside the else if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to eliminate the NA's within a nested for was to employ a nested if else

```
mi_df <- data.frame(
  "identifier" = 1:5, 
  "description" = c("a", "NA; ", "c", "d", "NA; "), 
  "period" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6, NA),
  "literature" = as.character(c("book1", "book2", NA, NA, "book3")),
  "URL" = c(NA, "web1", NA, "web2",NA)
)

lit_c <- which(colnames(mi_df) == "literature") 
url_c <- which(colnames(mi_df) == "URL")

for (c in 1:ncol(mi_df)) {
  for (r in 1:nrow(mi_df)) {
    if(c == lit_c) {            
      #cell <-  flatten(mi_df[r,c]) 
    } else if (c == url_c){
      cell <- if (is.na(mi_df[r,c])) "" else mi_df[r,c]  #to replace NA with ""                        
    } else {
      cell <- unlist(mi_df[r,c])
      cell <- gsub("NA; ", "xy", cell)  #gsub() used for replacement operations
    }
    mi_df[r,c] <- (cell)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only replace `NA` in the URL column

```
mi_df %>%  
  mutate(URL = URL %>% replace_na(""))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  identifier description period literature URL   
       <int> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>      <chr> 
1          1 a              1.2 book1      ""    
2          2 b              3.4 book2      "web1"
3          3 c              4.5 NA         ""    
4          4 d              5.6 NA         "web2"
5          5 e             10   book3      ""
```

But, if you want to replace all `NA` in the columns that contains characters, you can do

```
mi_df %>%  
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ replace_na(.x, "")))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  identifier description period literature URL   
       <int> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>      <chr> 
1          1 a              1.2 "book1"    ""    
2          2 b              3.4 "book2"    "web1"
3          3 c              4.5 ""         ""    
4          4 d              5.6 ""         "web2"
5          5 e             10   "book3"    ""
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The information comes from a database that might have changes and I would like to do all the adjustments within the nested loop.